# ImportError: No module named parse - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run `pipenv run main.py` I am met with the error `ImportError: No module named parse`.

I've looked around online but all I can find are people not using the correct python version, but I don't think that is the case here.

I first run `pipenv --three` to build the virtualenv using python 3.6.6. After that succeeds I am met with the previously stated error.

In my `__init.py__` file I'm importing parse through `from urllib.parse import urlparse`. The threads I can find online about the subject seems to be people using the Python 2 import syntax, but that's not the case here as far as I can tell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only importing that one function `urlparse`, not the entire package `urllib.parse`, so you don't have access to that yet. If you need the entire package you should import it with `from urllib import parse`.

You can also change `from urllib.parse import urlparse` to `from urllib.parse import urlparse as parse` if you only need the method, but then you would have clashing name (`parse` the module and `parse` the function). This works fine, as you can only access the function `parse` anyway, but this might get confusing later when you do need the entire package.

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 3? This is the error you get when running with Python 2.

Comment: I don't see how VSCode can say that I'm not. I've set the interpreter to use Python 3.6 (says so in the bottom left corner as well) and when I build the virtualenv I run `pipenv --three` and it says the virtualenv is being built using Python 3.6.

Comment: Why are you importing in `__init__.py`, and not just in the main python file `main.py`?